# angular translate with ngSanitize - how to display characters such as "&" or "<"

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, ngsanitize

I use angular-translate and it suggests to use ngSanitize. I just implemented it, but now, characters such as `&` display as `&amp;`, and the string `Next>` now displays as `Next&gt;` because they are sanitized.

My HTML is very simple such as:

```
<div>{{"SALES_MKT" | translate}}</div>
```

and in my translation file, I simply have something like:

```
var translationsEN = {
    SALES_MKT: 'Sales & Marketing'
}
```

There must be a way to escape these characters in a safe way? I have tried to use %xx codes, but they are not translated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sanitize should display the & properly. Are you having a problem when you use translate ?

Comment: I don't know angular, but I would say either the text is being parsed as text instead of as HTML, so you shouldn't 'sanitize' it; or it is being parsed as HTML but you 'sanitized' it twice.

Comment: The text translates just fine, only the special characters.